# Running user input that's formatted in a string

Tags: security

I'm aware that it's **strongly** advised to never execute user input as code, but I'm curious if my particular situation can be vulnerable to code injection:

1. The user provides text input in a front-end web form
2. A python script on the back-end takes user text input and uses it to create variable names for an R script (the variable names are stripped of any characters that violate R syntax for variable names)
3. We execute the R script, and return the results to the front-end page so the user can see the output

Is there any possible way we could be vulnerable to code injection?

note: We use python's format syntax to insert user variables; for example:

```python
'{varname} = dataframe${varname}'.format({'varname': stripped_user_provided_variable_name})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any possible way we could be vulnerable to code injection?

Absolutely. The general rule is that *you must escape/filter all user-supplied input* before you can use it anywhere in your application for anything else than a simple text string.

*Escape/filter* means that you need to remove each and every characters that is not required for the user function. Don't just filter what you think may be dangerous. If you expect a variable name, just accepting [a-zA-Z0-9] may be a good ides. Make sure you document the limitations in the manual/help.

Also make sure that you filter on the server side. Filtering on the client side only (web form, Javascript code, ...) isn't reliable as circumventing the client-side code and crafting custom POST actions is trivial.

If the user manages to craft an input that terminates the current statement (semicolon, `\r\n`, ... - dunno about R) and has the rest of their input interpreted as another statement then they've won.

Comment: this is really helpful! I didn't consider that users could create a custom POST